# Get data from Custom Database Table in my Event Observer fired after purchase made in Cart?

Tags: event-observer, mysql, collection

I have this code below that queries the Database for a collection or order records and it makes sure to `JOIN` my custom table and return it;s columns off data as well.

The custom table is named `web/web` and custom table columns are `order_original_id` which will be an ID that matches the order ID on the main table.  Also `shipbydate`

The PHP that gets this data...

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => $status));

// Filter out Order Types (RMA, RUSH, Normal)
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('ordertype_id', array('in' => $orderType));

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array(
    'web' => $collection->getTable('web/web')),
    'web.order_original_id = main_table.entity_id'
);

$collection->addOrder('shipbydate', 'ASC');


foreach ($collection as $order) {


    $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();

    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '    <td><strong>Order#</strong><br> <a href="work-order/order.php?orderid='.$order->getRealOrderId().'" target="_blank">'.$order->getRealOrderId().'</a></td>';
    $html .= '    <td><strong>Status:</strong><br> ' .$status_array[$order->getStatus()]. '</td>';
    $html .= '    <td><strong>Shipping Name:</strong><br>' .$shipping['firstname'].' '.$shipping['lastname'].'</td>';
    $html .= '    <td><strong>Shipping State:</strong><br>' .$shipping['region'].'</td>';
    $html .= '    <td><strong>Order Date:</strong><br> ' .$order->getCreatedAt(). '</td>';
    $html .= '    <td><strong>Ship Date:</strong><br>' .$order->getShipbydate(). '</td>';


    // Order Type (RMA, Rush, Normal)
    $order_type = $order->getOrdertypeId();


}
```

---

Moving on now what I am doing is using an Event Observer that is fired when a purchase is made in the shopping cart.  It gets the order data and then I have access to it in which I then insert it into a 3rd party DB table.

The problem is that I need to somehow get the data from my custom add-on table in this Observer code!

Here is that code...

**observer.php**

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
Mage::log(var_export($order->debug(), true), null, 'nam_order_event.log');

$orderId = $order->getId();

//$order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();



if ($order->getId()) {

    $sign_type = 'Neon Sign';
    $design_number = '';
    $item_qty = $order->items_qty;
    $grand_total_price = $order->grand_total;
    $customer_id = $order->customer_id;

    // insert data into 3rd party DB tables

}
```

So using the code I just posted for Observer.php I need to somehow get the DB table data from DB table `web/web`

Any ideas on a solution?

---

**UPDATE 1: Requested Config.xml**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <web>
            <class>Company_Web_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>web_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </web>
        <web_mysql4>
            <class>Company_Web_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <web>
                    <table>web</table>
                </web>
            </entities>
        </web_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <web_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Company_Web</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </web_setup>
        <web_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </web_write>
        <web_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </web_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <web>
            <class>Company_Web_Block</class>
        </web>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <web>
            <class>Company_Web_Helper</class>
        </web>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Comment: When you set up your additional table, did you set up model resources as well? The general idea is that you can set these up and then grab your table data with a typical `Mage::getModel('web/web')->getCollection()` and basically using it like you would any other Magento model.

Comment: The table was there when I joined the company, I am looking into the code to find out though

Comment: Check out the module's `config.xml` - You should have a node under `global >> models` that might look like `<web_resource>` that defines a model resource class and any entities and their table.

Comment: If the module is Company_Web it has everything you need. It is a demo module i saw around.

Comment: @pspahn Sorry got tied up with the boss.  You are correct it is a module some Indians built before I joined company and they didn't even bother to rename!  Based on this info, do you think it;s possible to get the data from my existing Event Observer code?

Comment: @mbalparda Believe you are correct!  I am not sure how to make it useful to me yet though? `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();` I am hoping I can somehow get it from this point...

Comment: Please post relevant sections of config.xml

Comment: @pspahn Thanks I added to the bottom of my question above

Comment: So does `Mage::getModel('web/web')->getCollection()` return your records? You should be able to work with this model as any other standard model in Magento, including dealing with collections, filtering, saving, etc.

Comment: @pspahn I will have to try and test.  As mentioned I need to get the data from that model inside of order event observer.  All I can do is log data since I cant stop the event to see it;s output when a live order is made.  I need to get the data from this model/table for the record that the event observer has loaded.  It seems I will just have to do about 100 fake orders logging and tweaking to test this.  That is why I hate observers, you cannot easily debug them

Answer (score 2):

1. Get a dev environment you can test what you are doing, this is a horrible comment:

   > All I can do is log data since I cant stop the event to see it;s output when a live order is made.
2. You can just load your data via: `Mage::getModel('web/web')->load($orderId, 'order_original_id');`

Comment: 1) I know it;s horrrribbbble! I'm embarrassed to admit to it but my bosses site is so large I just haven't been able to get it for a dev server yet but you are right, it;s a bad choice!

2) I believe that is basically how I ended up doing it, thanks